# generate random exponentially distributed X data between zero and a max value

Tags: random-generation, exponential-distribution, range

For my work issues, I need to generate random exponential distributed X data between zero and a max value.

In my specific case range is (0,750)

I know about inverse distribution function (IDF) for exponential distribution. And if I create 10K random x values by using exponential IDF, then select the ones lower from 750; I think this won't be true and suitable for my case. I don't know why but I think this'll create some other distribution. (concluded after reading some posts here)

So I ask for the methodology steps required or any post here or any tutorial. Maybe I searched very inefficiently on the web cause I couldn't find any methodology info.

Can you please help me? Best regards

## EDIT for a better understanding of the question

I mean:

1. a histogram of my data should resemble the exponential PDF.
2. max value of the generated random numbers can be 750.

Assume I know the methodolgy and created n pieces random values with lambda value = 0,0004. If any other engineer would analyze these n failure time data, again he/she should say that "these data are distributed exponentially and the lambda value is 0,0004"

I hope these paragraphs tell what I meant better.

Comment: If it has a max value then it isn't exponentially distributed. So you need to explain what you mean by "random exponential distributed X data between zero and a max value". Do you mean that a histogram of your data should resemble the exponential PDF but cut off (truncated) at the max value? Or do you mean that values of the exponential distribution above your max value would be recorded at the max value, ie the data is censored? (Which might happen if you had eg sensor readings that had gone 'off the scale'.)

Comment: The question is not well posed. There are as many different exponential distributions as there are possible values of the mean, namely all the positive numbers. You need to specify a mean too. On a broader note, distributions with sharp cut-offs usually seem implausible to me but as you have said nothing on why you think this is a good idea detailed comment is difficult.

Comment: You would probably benefit from reading up about [truncation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(statistics)) and [censoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics))

Comment: I am editing the question for a better understanding. Thanks, best regards

Comment: Truncation says that *Truncation can be applied to any probability distribution and will lead to a new distribution, not usually one within the same family.* so I think this concept is not what I look for. Thanks, BR

Comment: Asking for a distribution to be (1) exponential and (2) have a maximum value is incompatible, though - the exponential distribution can take *all* positive real numbers as its value, without upper bound. If there is a sharp cut-off, then anyone who looks at a histogram can see that the distribution is not exponential.

Comment: I agree with @Silverfish. This question seems based on a contradiction and the discussion is cycling around that contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Define a distribution $f(x) = \gamma\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, $x\in[0, c]$. Edit: This is the conditional distribution of $X\mid X < c$.

Then, in order for it to be a distribution, $\gamma = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-\lambda c}}$.

Using rejection sampling with the exponential distribution as a proposal we get that $\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\epsilon}\mathbb{1}(x<c)$ can be used as the rejection rate. A MATLAB implementation could look like this:

```
%% Truncated exponential distribution
gamma = @(lambda, c) 1/(1 - exp(-lambda*c));
f = @(x, lambda, c) gamma(lambda, c)*lambda*exp(-lambda*x).*(x < c);
G = 1e3;
x = 0:900;
lambda = 0.001; 
c = 750;
%% AR-Sampling
eps = 0.01;
M = gamma(lambda, c) + eps;
MM = gamma(lambda, c)/M;
t = zeros(G, 1);
for k = 1:G
    not_accepted = true;
    while not_accepted
        t_star = exprnd(1/lambda);
        if rand < (t_star < c)/MM
            not_accepted = false;
            t(k) = t_star;
        end
    end
end

%% MH-sampling
G = 1e6;
t = zeros(G, 1);
for k = 2:G
    t_star = t(k-1) + randn*10;
    if rand < exp(-lambda*(t_star - t(k-1)))*(t_star > 0)*(t_star < c)
        t(k) = t_star;
    else
        t(k) = t(k-1);
    end
end
```

Comment: This produces a truncated exponential distribution, rather than an exponential distribution, which according to their question the OP specifically does not want. But this might be the closest thing to an answer in the circumstances.

Comment: I reason like this: Staying within the exponential distribution will not be possible. But for a suitable lambda and c the truncated will behave almost like an exponential distribution. The alternative would be to switch to another distribution which is decaying faster. For instance the half-normal distribution.

Comment: (+1): when I worked on [truncated normal distributions](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/simulation-of-truncated-normal-variables-reprint/), I used this definition of restricting the normal pdf to a given interval.